# How to split string by {} if there are also {} inside it?

Tags: php

Say I have this string:

`{"name":"Daniel"}{}{}{}{},"age":"{5}"}
{"name":"John"{}{}{}{},"age":"{5}"}
{"name":"Lawrence"{}{}{}{},"age":"{5}"}` about 3 million more...

How can I get foreach the {}'s so that I can get the name & age of each person, even though I already have { and }'s everywhere?

Comment: Use a regular expression to extract the strings after `"name":` and `"age":`. The `{}` are irrelevant.

Comment: Problem is that name and age isn't the only data inside those {}, I have around 40 different data.

Comment: Then you should explain what you're trying to do more clearly. It still seems like you can just match on `"xxx":"yyy"` types of strings, ignoring the {}.

Comment: Is it possible to split by {}?

Comment: Sure, `explode('{}', $string)` will do that. I don't see what it has to do with what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You can't just say "I have this string" without explaining how it ended up that way. This is asking for clumsy workarounds without ever fixing the source of your issues. Please see http://xyproblem.info/ before figuring out how to split things up.

Comment: Your example is not regular therefore we can't help you without a proper example. Your names is only enclosed in `""` where as age is enclosed in `"{}"`

Comment: Explode worked, thank you!

Comment: This looks like JSON and, if so you should be using [`json_decode()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) instead of trying to do it yourself.

Answer (score -3):

**The only way you have to use string replace for this type of data**

```
$as = '{"name":"Daniel"}{}{}{}{},"age":"{5}"}';
$as = str_replace('{}','', $as);
$as = str_replace('"{','', $as);
$as = str_replace('"}','', $as);
$as = str_replace('{','', $as);
$as = str_replace('}','', $as);
$as = str_replace('"name":"','', $as);
$as = str_replace('"age":','', $as);
$as = explode(',', $as);
print_r($as);
```

Comment: He said in a comment there are 40 different fields, not just `name` and `age`.

Comment: You can do all the `str_replace` at once by using an array of all the strings to match.

Comment: Hmm. Then he must need to give more detail. Do R Records needs in any specific language or any language means in python it is possible .To get those all datas

Comment: Yes, he does. See my comment above beginning with "Then you should explain what you're trying to do more clearly".

Comment: Yes  Barmar You are right ,I agreed. He needs to be posted more details what he wants.